# whatsmyip gives different IP from file_get_contents than browser

Tags: php, apache, static-ip-address

I have a static IP on my router. My PC runs apache on localhost.
When I open www.whatsmyip.org in my browser I get the static IP I was assigned from my ISP.
When I run

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("http://www.whatsmyip.org");
```

in apache from browser, on my PC's localhost server, it shows a different IP every time I run it.
Where's the issue? my ISP? my apache config? the way `get_file_contents` works on URLs?

Comment: should be the same ip

Comment: Is your browser using some sort of proxy by any chance?

Comment: Any proxies involved?

Comment: no proxies involved: PC - router with static IP assigned - ISP.

Comment: I tried that as well, same thing. IP changes every time I refresh php script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is funny one. It took me a while, but enjoyed it.

The source for that site contains:

```
<div>
    <!-- Please DO NOT use this site to power an IP bot, script or other IP-lookup software! -->
    <h1>Your IP Address is <span id="ip">a random ip</span></h1>
</div>
```

It is kind of anti bot mechanism (they even warn about it :D ). On page load it's replaced by your actual IP using Java Script.

I checked other sites and most of them use similar mechanism.

This one does not if you need to check
http://whatsmyip.net/